# Undo 'git add' before commit - need to remove added folder

Tags: git

I have run `git reset --soft "HEAD^"` command which has done undo my commit.

But now problem I am facing is...Files and folders are still seems added means in green.

Now to undo file added there is command for it i.e. `git reset HEAD <file>`

But it is not possible for me to run this command as I have lot of folders added.

So need command which can undo folder added.

Comment: `git reset HEAD` accepts a folder path just the same way as it does a file path. You can even list multiple folders in one line, delimited by spaces.

Comment: thanks...just add your answer here ...I will accept it

Comment: You should accept Gabriele's answer instead.

Comment: You were first, whose ans helped me. So I will give you prefrence

Comment: I posted without looking at the comments, but it's totally fine if @DCoder wants to add an answer. I'll take mine away :)

Comment: @ Gabriele Petronella:  I appreciate all efforts which put in by users. that's y I have up voted it as well ...don't remove ans

Comment: It's fairly common to come up with the same answer to an easy question. DCoder beat me at it by a minute, so if he likes he can converts his comment to an answer. Since we said the same thing, I will then remove mine in case he decides to do so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset HEAD the_directory_you_want_to_reset/
```

---

It's actually

```
git reset HEAD <paths>
```

not

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

meaning that you can pass any path (directories or files makes no difference).